# aplay lists the device, but pulseaudio thinks it's locked and won't detect it

Tags: usb, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

UPDATE 2021-07-08: I'm now using Pop!_OS 21.04 and this problem *appears* to have been resolved. I have just now tested with **pulseaudio 14.2** and **pipewire 0.3.24** and I was able to disconnect and reconnect a headset (connected by USB/stereo jack adapter) about 10 times in the span of one minute. No recurrence of the problem I describe below. I presume this works on Ubuntu 21.04 as well.

I'm using Pop!_OS 20.10 and I have an intermittent problem that seems to happen reliably when I disconnect and reconnect my USB microphone "too often" or "too many times". I would like to at least learn about a workaround less drastic than rebooting my machine.

It goes like this: I disconnect my USB microphone, then I reconnect it. If I do this 2 or 3 times within 30 seconds, eventually pulseaudio tells me this:

```
    D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC1 is accessible: yes                                                             
    D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/sound/card1 is busy: no                         
    D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Loading module-alsa-card with arguments 'device_id="1" name="usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"'                        
    D: [pulseaudio] reserve-wrap.c: Device 'Audio1' already locked.
    E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
    I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/sound/card1 (alsa_card.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone-00) failed to load module.
    I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 3 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
```

I don't see my microphone in the various pulseaudio tools, even though aplay lists the device in `aplay -l`

```
    card 1: Microphone [Yeti Stereo Microphone], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If I reboot, then I can connect my USB microphone again, but I'm looking for a workaround less drastic than this that would reset whatever state is messed up when I disconnect and reconnect the USB audio device "too often".

Comment: *If I do this 2 or 3 times within 30 seconds* Out of curiosity, why would you that, are you trying to fix some other issue by reconnecting?

Comment: No. I discovered the problem accidentally and then I figured out that this reliably reproduces the problem. I was moving devices from the USB port to a hub one day and then suddenly Pop! wouldn't detect any microphones. That's how I stumbled upon the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed some of the comments here:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/809

Killing pipewire and then restarting pulseaudio fixed the problem:

```
systemctl --user stop pipewire.service
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

It appears to be a race between pipewire and pulseaudio.  I don't know anything about pipewire, but it sometimes seems to grab a lock on the USB audio device before pulseaudio can access it.

To permanently disable pipewire:

```
sudo systemctl --global stop pipewire.service
sudo systemctl --global disable pipewire.service
```

I don't know what service(s) pipewire provides that I might miss, but so far nothing :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was with this problem and I've tested, all my devices appeared after I disabled pipewire, I can confirm that this work with Ubuntu 20.04.3 with pulseaudio 13.99.1

Comment: My current approach is to just uninstall pipewire completely :)  Works like a charm!